# Setting the api-version in httpcontext for integration tests.[Already answered similar SO question doesn't apply to me]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998343/how-to-set-api-version-related-data-to-httpcontext-for-unit-testing-in-net-core) question is what I need to do but I don't have enough reputation to comment on Vikram's answer.

I can't use Mocks. Our tests are already using a proper HttpContext object in the tests. All I need is to set the api-version of the httpcontext since I need to grab it later on from ActionExecutedContext.

EDIT:
In a test file:

```
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = this.ServiceProviderBuilder.Build(regions).Object
        };

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.Add("api-version", serviceVersion.GetDescription());
        httpContext.Request.QueryString = queryBuilder.ToQueryString();
```

This `httpContext` is then assigned to `ControllerContext` that is used by `myController`.

I'm using myController to make a call:

```
                    var context = new ActionExecutedContext(
                new ActionContext
                {
                    HttpContext = myController.HttpContext,
                    RouteData = new RouteData(),
                    ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor()
                },
                new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
                myController);

    IActionResult result = await myController.GetInfoAsync()
```

In my own ActionFilterAttribute:

```
        /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // I use the requestedApiVersion later on in the code
        ApiVersion requestedApiVersion = context.HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to set ttpContext.Request.Query?You can try to replace [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250145/how-to-modify-form-querystring-values-at-middleware-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: @YiyiYou I did something similar  `QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.Add("api-version", serviceVersion.GetDescription());
httpContext.Request.QueryString = queryBuilder.ToQueryString();`
but context.HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion() is still null.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this can be achieved depending on your goals.

As is currently written, you'd need to make sure that `AddApiVersioning()` has been called against your `ServiceProviderBuilder`. It's unclear if that is part of your setup.

You didn't mention which version of API Versioning you're using, but even without any other registration, things still *might* have worked. The issue could be related to `serviceVersion.GetDescription()`. It's not clear what this does, but it should simply provide the API version string. If the specified value is invalid, this will cause the `HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()` extension method to return `null`.

By design, a parsing failure doesn't cause a runtime exception; however, you would have seen the routing system not match the requested endpoint. `null`, in this context, is a perfectly normal return value.

It's hard to tell from this setup, but if all you need to do is simulate the requested, parsed API version, there is a much simpler way. The extension method is really just a shortcut to get a specific property of a *feature*:

```cs
var feature = httpContext.Features.Get<IApiVersioningFeature>();
var rawApiVersion = feature.RawRequestedApiVersion; // unparsed
var apiVersion = feature.RequestedApiVersion;
```

The feature properties are read/write. There aren't many use cases to explicitly set these values, but testing is one of them. The runtime behavior as to when this feature is initialized varies, but in the latest implementations, it's always created and set through the extension method. To be absolutely sure, all you need to do is setup the feature explicitly in the test:

```cs
IApiVersioningFeature feature = new ApiVersioningFeature(httpContext);
feature.ApiVersion = new ApiVersion(2, 0);
httpContext.Features.Set(feature);
```

> Note: The key in the `IFeatureCollection` is the type. It is therefore important to use the `IApiVersioningFeature` interface and not a concrete type.

At this point, you can mock or setup the `HttpContext` to your heart's content. `DefaultHttpContext` shouldn't require any additional setup. If you were mocking `HttpContext`, then it might look like:

```cs
// arrange
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
var features = new FeatureCollection();
IApiVersioningFeature feature = new ApiVersioningFeature(httpContext.Object);

feature.RequestedApiVersion = new ApiVersion(2, 0);
features.Set(feature);
httpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Features).Returns(features);

// act
var result = httpContext.Object.GetRequestedApiVersion();

// assert
result.Should().Be(feature.RequestedApiVersion);
```